# How to print multipliers 3 and 5, but not print multipliers 15?

Tags: c, multiplication

Here's the program I already made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i,n,t,t2;

    printf("enter limit number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        t = i * 3;
        t2 = i * 5;

        printf("%d, " ,t);
        printf("%d, ",t2);
    }
}
```

How to print multipliers of `3` and `5`, but not print multipliers `15`?

Comment: Please indent the code.

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: And please show the required output for a given input. For example, you print two multiples in the same loop. Do you simply skip one of the pair if the multiple is 15? And what about when the multiple is 30, 45 etc?

Comment: You should step to the next chapter in your C book: "Conditional statement" `if` & co.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How to print multiplier `3` and `5`, but not print multiplier `15`?

So what can you know from this, the number that is being printed when divided with `15` must no produce remainder as `0` because then, it'd be multiplier of `15` so just put your printf statements in a if loop like this:

```
if((t % 15) != 0)
{
    printf("%d, " ,t);
}    
if((t2 % 15) != 0)
{    
    printf("%d, ",t2);
}
```

see this for working example: https://ideone.com/2k0qLW

Comment: (I'm not the one who downvoted you. While the answer doesn't address a number of problems with the OP's code, it does address the question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an integer is a evenly divisible by another by using the modulus operator. If the result (the remainder) is zero, then it's evenly divisible.

Your code doesn't actually stop at the limit, it prints the numbers out of order, it prints a trailing comma, and it doesn't print a terminating newline. Fixed:

```
int matches = 0;
for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
    if ((i % 3) == 0 || (i % 5) == 0) {
        if ((i % 15) != 0) {
            if (matches++) {
                printf(", ");
            }

            printf("%d", t);
        }
    }
}

if (matches)
    printf("\n");
```

Comment: With a limit of 10, it prints 50 but not 48. Not only does it go above the limit, it misses some values!